# MongoDB passing query from request

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to add filteration to my product list by product types from query.

Lets say I want to implement this:

```
Product.find({
   "product_type.name": {
     $in: ["A", "B"]
   }
})
```

Which filters my products which either has type "A" or "B". But I dont always want to filter, thats why from the request I see whether we have this filteration or not. So I check like:

```
let query = {}
if (req.query.product_type) {
    query.product_type.name =  {
     $in: ["A", "B"]
   }
}
```

Where   `product_type = ["A", "B"]` coming from request.

Then:

```
Product.find(query)
```

when I run this I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined.
```

I want the query value to be like

```
   "product_type.name": {
     $in: ["A", "B"]
   }
```

Comment: `query["product_type.name"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as @willis suggested do the following

```js
let query = {};

if (Array.isArray(req.query.product_type) && req.query.product_type.length > 0) {
    query["product_type.name"] =  {
        $in: req.query.product_type
    }
}
```